# extern for class instance with template

Tags: c++, templates, extern

I have the following instance of a class with template in main.cpp

```
template <class T>
T mypair<T>::getmax ()
{
  T retval;
  retval = a>b? a : b;
  return retval;
}

mypair <int> myobject (100, 75);
```

I wish to have a header file that has an extern to this class instance, i.e "myobject".

How can this be achieved?

I already tried:

```
* extern mypair<int> myobject;
* extern template mypair<int> myobject;
* extern template class mypair<int> myobject;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: You list three alternatives for the declaration of `myobject`. Which one of them have you *tried*? Which of them worked? Which did not? If none of them worked, what problems did you have? Please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi, I tried the first one above for the instantsiation of myboject, BUT the question is how to create an extern for it in a header file.

Comment: @RichardCritten: Not even close. About nothing about externs there. Sure, split the example, template to .h, instantiation to .cpp, doesn't change the outcome: `error: expected initializer before '<' token`, or `error: explicit instantiation of non-template`

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the template class defined in a header which must be included before the extern declaration.

If your compiler encounters a header which says `extern mypair<int> myobject;` it has no clue what kind of entity `mypair` is. You must first define it - through including the header containing the template class.

Comment: Thanks, I will review it.